# how to get XML from xml.pm7 in Python

Tags: python-3.x, xml

**Short context/goal:**
We get those xml.p7m files from our Italian creditors via mail, and have to process them, so we can pay those.
The goal is to automate this process, so people don't have to manually validate the data.
If we don't get all the data we need to automatically process the invoice, we create a pdf so people can validate the data.

**The Problem:**
*(I can't attach the full xml.pm7 because of all those characters in there that shouldn't be there, so I did it via picture, but the relevant tag can be copy and pasted)*

1. I don't speak Italian, so it's hard for me to find the
   information I need to continue with this task
2. Since we cant parse the .p7m files with an xml parser (not well
   formed, obviously), I have to remove all the unneeded stuff, so we can parse the xml part. Which works in (so far) ~ 450 of 532 mails. With "manually replacing error tags" (see below) we reach for those a 100%, but adding exceptions every now and then isn't the correct way to handle this:

**The relevant code:**

```
# Some p7m have some things like ♦♥ in it, they need to be removed (and while we're at it, remove the signature so it's well formed)
# Special Characters which translate to --> \x04\xc2\x82\x03\xc3\xa8
# <Nazione>IT</Nazione>♦♥è
# <Descrizione>nr ordine 9♦♥è303067091</Descrizione>
# <NumeroLinea>6<\Numero♦♥èLinea>
# <Quant♦♥èita>0.00</Quantita>
# </Anagraf♦♥èica>
def getXmlTextRemovedSignature(path, filePath, m_iv_id, mailSubject, amountOfAttachments, logger):    
        txt = ""
        parseError = 0
        try:
            with open(filePath, encoding='latin-1') as f:
                try:
                    txt = f.read()
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.errorLog("Couldn't read file text: {}".format(e))
            
                # no opening tag to find --> no xml --> decode the file, save it, and get the text
                if not re.findall('<',txt):
                    image_64_decode = base64.decodebytes(txt.encode())
                    image_result = open(path + 'decoded.xml', 'wb') # create a writable image and write the decoding result
                    image_result.write(image_64_decode)
                    image_result.close()
                    txt = open(path + 'decoded.xml', encoding='latin-1').read()

                try:
                    txt = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9<>\'\+\-\,\?\"\.\=\/\:\r\n\t\!\[\] {1,}]', '', txt)
                    if re.findall(r'<\?xml', txt):
                        txt = '<?xml' + re.split(r'<\?xml',txt,1)[1]
                    else:
                        tag = re.findall(r'<.{0,5}FatturaElettronica', txt)[0]
                        txt = tag +  re.split(tag, txt,1)[1]

                    if re.findall(r'<\/.{0,5}FatturaElettronica>', txt):
                        tag = re.findall(r'<\/.{0,5}FatturaElettronica>', txt)[0]
                        txt = re.split(tag, txt, 1)[0] +  tag 

                except Exception as e:
                    logger.errorLog("Error while removing the signature, m_iv_id = {}, mailsubject: {}, error: {}".format(m_iv_id, mailSubject, e))
                
                # Things to replace 
                # txt = txt.replace('PDatiRiepilogo','DatiRiepilogo')
                # txt = txt.replace('DatiRiepiDlogo', 'DatiRiepilogo')
                # txt = txt.replace('DatiRiepiloBgo', 'DatiRiepilogo')
                # txt = txt.replace('j/DatiRiepilogo', '/DatiRiepilogo')
                # txt = txt.replace('AliquotIaIVA', 'AliquotaIVA')
                # txt = txt.replace('AliquotaIVA', 'AliquotaIVA')
                # txt = txt.replace('AliquoJtaIVA', 'AliquotaIVA')
                # txt = txt.replace('AliquotaHIVA', 'AliquotaIVA')
                # txt = txt.replace('AliquotaGIVA', 'AliquotaIVA')
                # txt = txt.replace('cAliquotaIVA', 'AliquotaIVA')
                # txt = txt.replace('UnitaMiEsura', 'UnitaMisura')
                # txt = txt.replace('UnitaMisuraE', 'UnitaMisura')
                # txt = txt.replace('De.ttaglioLinee', 'DettaglioLinee')
                # txt = txt.replace('DettaglioLin-ee', 'DettaglioLinee')
                # txt = txt.replace('Dett?aglioLinee', 'DettaglioLinee')
                # txt = txt.replace('DePttaglioLinee', 'DettaglioLinee')
                # txt = txt.replace('DettaglioLiEnee', 'DettaglioLinee')
                # txt = txt.replace('DettaglioLinee+', 'DettaglioLinee')
                # txt = txt.replace('Dettaglio0Linee', 'DettaglioLinee')
                # txt = txt.replace('ImponibileImportoS', 'ImponibileImporto')
                # txt = txt.replace('SNumeroLinea', 'NumeroLinea')
                # txt = txt.replace('FatturaElettronic!aBody', 'FatturaElettronicaBody')
                # txt = txt.replace('/FatturaEle    ttronica', '/FatturaElettronica')
                # txt = txt.replace('SpeseAccessorXie', 'SpeseAccessorie')
                # txt = txt.replace('Quantit]a', 'Quantita')
                # txt = txt.replace('DatiPaga4mento]a', 'DatiPagamento')
                # txt = txt.replace('DatiPaga4mento', 'DatiPagamento')
                # txt = txt.replace('IXmposta', 'Imposta')
                # txt = txt.replace('DataScfadenzaPagamento', 'DataScadenzaPagamento')
                # txt = txt.replace('DataScadenzaPagame/nto', 'DataScadenzaPagamento')
                # txt = txt.replace('Dat=aScadenzaPagamento', 'DataScadenzaPagamento')
                # txt = txt.replace('RiferimLentoTesto', 'RiferimentoTesto')
                # txt = txt.replace('CodiceTipoN', 'CodiceTipo')
                # txt = txt.replace('D[ettaglioPagamento', 'DettaglioPagamento')
                # txt = txt.replace('DatiBeniServizi', 'DatiBeniServizi')
                # txt = txt.replace('AttachmeBnt', 'Attachment')
                # txt = txt.replace('ModalitaPagamhento', 'ModalitaPagamento')
                # txt = txt.replace('ModalXitaPagamento', 'ModalitaPagamento')
    
                try:
                    ET.fromstring(txt)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(parseError)
                    parseError = 3
                    logger.errorLog("Couldn't parse xml, m_iv_id = {}, mailsubject: {}, error: {}".format(m_iv_id, mailSubject, e))

                if txt:
                    amountOfAttachments[0]+=1
                return {"xml" : txt, "parseError" : parseError}
        
        except Exception as e:
            logger.errorLog("Error while removing the signature, m_iv_id = {}, mailsubject: {}, path: {}, error: {}".format(m_iv_id, mailSubject, path, e))
```

**p7m example:**

```
    0�  *�H��
    ��0�10
        `�He
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p:FatturaElettronica xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" versione="FPR12" xmlns:p="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2">
  <FatturaElettronicaHeader>
    <DatiTrasmissione>
      <IdTrasmittente>
        <IdPaese>IT</IdPaese>
        <IdCodice>02002750483</IdCodice>
      </IdTrasmittente>
      <ProgressivoInvio>000YP</ProgressivoInvio>
      <FormatoTrasmissione>FPR12</FormatoTrasmissione>
      <CodiceDestinatario>0000000</CodiceDestinatario>
      <PECDestinatario>CENSORED</PECDestinatario>
    </DatiTrasmissione>
    <CedentePrestatore>
      <DatiAnagrafici>
        <IdFiscaleIVA>
          <IdPaese>IT</IdPaese>
          <IdCodice>CENSORED</IdCodice>
        </IdFiscaleIVA>
        <Anagrafica>
          <Denominazione>CENSORED</Denominazione>
        </Anagrafica>
        <RegimeFiscale>RF01��</RegimeFiscale>
      </DatiAnagrafici>
      <Sede>
        <Indirizzo>CENSORED</Indirizzo>
        <CAP>70128</CAP>
        <Comune>Bari</Comune>
        <Provincia>BA</Provincia>
        <Nazione>IT</Nazione>
      </Sede>
      <IscrizioneREA>
        <Ufficio>BA</Ufficio>
        <NumeroREA>482324</NumeroREA>
        <CapitaleSociale>300000.00</CapitaleSociale>
        <SocioUnico>SM</SocioUnico>
        <StatoLiquidazione>LN</StatoLiquidazione>
      </IscrizioneREA>
    </CedentePrestatore>
    <CessionarioCommittente>
      <DatiAnagrafici>
        <IdFiscaleIVA>
          <IdPaese>IT</IdPaese>
          <IdCodice>CENSORED</IdCodice>
        </IdFiscaleIVA>
        <Anagrafica>
          <Denominazione>CENSORED </Denominazione>
        </Anagrafica>
      </DatiAnagrafici>
      <Sede>
        <Indirizzo>CENSORED</Indirizzo>
        <CAP>39100</CAP>
        <Comune>Bolzano</Comune>
        <Pro��vincia>BZ</Provincia>
        <Nazione>IT</Nazione>
      </Sede>
    </CessionarioCommittente>
    <TerzoIntermediarioOSoggettoEmittente>
      <DatiAnagrafici>
        <IdFiscaleIVA>
          <IdPaese>IT</IdPaese>
          <IdCodice>CENSORED</IdCodice>
        </IdFiscaleIVA>
        <CodiceFiscale>CENSORED</CodiceFiscale>
        <Anagrafica>
          <Denominazione>CENSORED</Denominazione>
        </Anagrafica>
      </DatiAnagrafici>
    </TerzoIntermediarioOSoggettoEmittente>
    <SoggettoEmittente>TZ</SoggettoEmittente>
  </FatturaElettronicaHeader>
  <FatturaElettronicaBody>
    <DatiGenerali>
      <DatiGeneraliDocumento>
        <TipoDocumento>TD01</TipoDocumento>
        <Divisa>EUR</Divisa>
        <Data>2021-09-07</Data>
        <Numero>288/2021</Numero>
        <ImportoTotaleDocumento>101.27</ImportoTotaleDocumento>
        <Causale>OR. 9303258741
COD. 43583</Causale>
      </DatiGeneraliDocumento>
    </DatiGenerali>
��    <DatiBeniServizi>
      <DettaglioLinee>
        <NumeroLinea>1</NumeroLinea>
        <CodiceArticolo>
          <CodiceTipo>INTERNO</CodiceTipo>
          <CodiceValore>OFF</CodiceValore>
        </CodiceArticolo>
        <Descrizione>LAVORO D'OFFICINA JEEP RENEGADE GE721ZJ KM 8763 </Descrizione>
        <UnitaMisura>NR</UnitaMisura>
        <PrezzoUnitario>0.0000</PrezzoUnitario>
        <PrezzoTotale>0.0000</PrezzoTotale>
        <AliquotaIVA>22.00</AliquotaIVA>
      </DettaglioLinee>
      <DettaglioLinee>
        <NumeroLinea>2</NumeroLinea>
        <CodiceArticolo>
          <CodiceTipo>INTERNO</CodiceTipo>
          <CodiceValore>OFF</CodiceValore>
        </CodiceArticolo>
        <Descrizione>SOSTITUZIONE FILTRO OLIO COD. 46337528 </Descrizione>
        <Quantita>1.00</Quantita>
        <UnitaMisura>NR</UnitaMisura>
        <PrezzoUnitario>8.4900</PrezzoUnitario>
        <PrezzoTotale>8.4900</PrezzoTotale>
        <AliquotaIVA>22.00</AliquotaIVA>
��      </DettaglioLinee>
      <DettaglioLinee>
        <NumeroLinea>3</NumeroLinea>
        <CodiceArticolo>
          <CodiceTipo>INTERNO</CodiceTipo>
          <CodiceValore>OFF</CodiceValore>
        </CodiceArticolo>
        <Descrizione>OLIO MOTORE 5W-30 4,5 LITRI  </Descrizione>
        <Quantita>1.00</Quantita>
        <UnitaMisura>NR</UnitaMisura>
        <PrezzoUnitario>51.5200</PrezzoUnitario>
        <PrezzoTotale>51.5200</PrezzoTotale>
        <AliquotaIVA>22.00</AliquotaIVA>
      </DettaglioLinee>
      <DettaglioLinee>
        <NumeroLinea>4</NumeroLinea>
        <CodiceArticolo>
          <CodiceTipo>INTERNO</CodiceTipo>
          <CodiceValore>OFF</CodiceValore>
        </CodiceArticolo>
        <Descrizione>LAVORO DI MESSA IN OPERA </Descrizione>
        <Quantita>1.00</Quantita>
        <UnitaMisura>NR</UnitaMisura>
        <PrezzoUnitario>23.0000</PrezzoUnitario>
        <PrezzoTotale>23.0000</PrezzoTotale>
        <AliquotaIVA>22.00</Aliquo�JtaIVA>
      </DettaglioLinee>
      <DatiRiepilogo>
        <AliquotaIVA>22.00</AliquotaIVA>
        <ImponibileImporto>83.01</ImponibileImporto>
        <Imposta>18.26</Imposta>
        <EsigibilitaIVA>I</EsigibilitaIVA>
      </DatiRiepilogo>
    </DatiBeniServizi>
  </FatturaElettronicaBody>
</p:FatturaElettronica>
```

*I can't copy and paste the full .p7m text, sadly, there is a lot more stuff after the closing tag like this:*[image]

after I used my function, I still get something like this:

```
<AliquotaIVA>22.00</AliquoJtaIVA>
```

Aliquo**J**taIVA

after I replaced the unwanted stuff from the original:

```
<AliquotaIVA>22.00</Aliquo�JtaIVA>
```

Can someone help me out in how to parse those xml.p7m with python(or another language, I really don't care at this point)?

I don't see a logic there, and I really don't want to maintain all the special cases for the next year or so (those would be in a database table btw., so we don't have to adjust the code all the time, but for testing purposes it's hard coded)

**Edit:**
Another Problem would be if those special characters would appear in a tag with numbers

Comment: I don't know anything about p7m, but I found this: https://github.com/Laischon/P7M-Extract. And you have already asked and answered a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68300185/407651. What is different this time?

Comment: @mzjn At this point i hadn't had the samplesize I now have and I din't kknew that those "special characters" can occur in the tags.

Comment: It seems like the [tag:openssl] and [tag:pkcs#7] tags would be appropriate. Maybe you can use this information: http://enricorossi.org/blog/2016/view_p7m_file_with_openssl/.